# Set LI element to inactive state on clicking button in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

OK, so this is a noob question and the answer is probably right under my nose but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Basically, I am making a To-do list in React and want a way for the user to mark an item as completed.

I've tried setting it through a parent container's state, then accessing that state through the elements props but it's not working.

Here is my code so far. See the getInitialState function, onCompleted, return function of ListContainer, and the Item.

```
var ListContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      numChildren: 0,
      list: [],
      disabled: false
    };
  },
  onAddChild: function() {
    var inputValue = document.getElementById('itemAdder').value;
    var ul = document.getElementById('list');

    var newList = this.state.list;
    if(inputValue !== '') {
      newList.push(inputValue);
      ul.style.display = 'block';
    }
    this.setState({
      numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1,
      list: newList
    });
  },
  onDeleteChild: function(index) {
    this.state.list.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      list: this.state.list
    });
  },
  onCompleted: function() {
    this.setState({
      disabled: true
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    var children = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.list.length; i++) {
      children.push(<Item key={'item_' + i} number={i} onDeleteChild={this.onDeleteChild} completed={this.state.onCompleted} content={this.state.list[i]}/>);
    };
    return (
      <List addChild={this.onAddChild}>
        {children}
      </List>
    );
  }
});

var List = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div id="listContainer">
        <h1 className="no-margins even-padding page-header ">To do list</h1>
        <div className="even-padding form-inline">
          <input type="text" name="itemAdder" id="itemAdder" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter things that need doing..." />
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.props.addChild}>Add item</button>
          <ul id="list" className="no-margins list">
            {this.props.children}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Item = React.createClass({
  complete: function() {
    this.props.completed;
  },
  delete: function() {
    this.props.onDeleteChild(this.props.number);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <li className="clearfix">
        {this.props.content}
        <div className="pull-right">
          <button onClick={this.complete} id="completed" className="btn btn-success btn-xs">&#x2714;</button>
          <button id="remove" onClick={this.delete} className="btn btn-danger btn-xs">&#x2718;</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div id="main" className="page-wrap">
        <ListContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Instead of your list just being an array with the values, make it an array with objects where each object contains the value and its state. For example `list: [{value: "foo", state: 0}, {value: "bar", state: 1}]`

Comment: but what is _value_?

Answer (score 2):

First of all the children list inside the for loop is incorrect. The completed prop should be passed like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.list.length; i++) {
  children.push(<Item key={'item_' + i} number={i} onDeleteChild={this.onDeleteChild} completed={this.onCompleted} content={this.state.list[i]}/>);
};
```

Also the state you have costructed has the incorrect structure. Every item in the list should have its own property disabled. If you don't do so, either all the items will be diabled or all the items will be enabled.

To fix that, remove the disabled attribute from your return statement of getInitialState and change your onAddChild method

```
onAddChild: function() {
var inputValue = document.getElementById('itemAdder').value;
var ul = document.getElementById('list');

var newList = this.state.list;
if(inputValue !== '') {
  newList.push({value: inputValue, disabled: false});
  ul.style.display = 'block';
}
this.setState({
  numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1,
  list: newList
});
```

}

Now change your children list like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.list.length; i++) {
  children.push(<Item key={'item_' + i} number={i} onDeleteChild={this.onDeleteChild} completed={this.onCompleted} content={this.state.list[i].value}/>);
};
```

Now your onCompleted method must be passed the index of the item which has to be updated

```
onCompleted: function(itemIndex) {
    var newList = this.state.list.slice();
    newList[itemIndex].disabled = true;
    this.setState({
      list: newList
    });
}
```

Finally, the render method of the Item component has to be updated. Just pass the index of the list item when the onCLick of the first button is triggered i.e change the **complete** method inside the List Component like this:

```
complete: function() {
    this.props.completed(this.props.number) // Passing the index of the item as an argument
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, a small problem arises with this line: `newList.push({value: inputValue, disabled: false});` I get an 'unexpected type cast' error from _value_. Any idea what I need to do? Cheers!

Comment: I dont get any error https://jsfiddle.net/swapnil95/rdfdn5d4/2/
Open the console and see the updated states

Comment: OK but it's not disabling the element?